# Using an API to get all data from multiple keys of the same name python

Tags: python, python-3.x, api, dictionary, weather

I am very new to APIs and I am trying to make a Python script to tell me the day time high for my city. I have the API set up fine and the data it outputs is this:

```
{
    "SiteRep":{
            "Wx":{
                "Param":[
                {
                    "name":"FDm",
                    "units":"C",
                    "$":"Feels Like Day 
                    Maximum Temperature"
                },
                {
                    "name":"FNm",
                    "units":"C",
                    "$":"Feels Like Night Minimum Temperature"
                },
                {
                    "name":"Dm",
                    "units":"C",
                    "$":"Day Maximum Temperature"
                },
                {
                    "name":"Nm",
                    "units":"C",
                    "$":"Night Minimum Temperature"
                },
                {
                    "name":"Gn",
                    "units":"mph",
                    "$":"Wind Gust Noon"
                },
                {
                    "name":"Gm",
                    "units":"mph",
                    "$":"Wind Gust Midnight"
                },
                {
                    "name":"Hn",
                    "units":"%",
                    "$":"Screen Relative Humidity Noon"
                },
                {
                    "name":"Hm",
                    "units":"%",
                    "$":"Screen Relative Humidity Midnight"
                },
                {
                    "name":"V",
                    "units":"",
                    "$":"Visibility"
                },
                {
                    "name":"D",
                    "units":"compass",
                    "$":"Wind Direction"
                },
                {
                    "name":"S",
                    "units":"mph",
                    "$":"Wind Speed"
                },
                {
                    "name":"U",
                    "units":"",
                    "$":"Max UV Index"
                },
                {
                    "name":"W",
                    "units":"",
                    "$":"Weather Type"
                },
                {
                    "name":"PPd",
                    "units":"%",
                    "$":"Precipitation Probability Day"
                },
                {
                    "name":"PPn",
                    "units":"%",
                    "$":"Precipitation Probability Night"
                }
            ]
            },
                "DV":{
                    "dataDate":"2017-05-28T17:00:00Z",
                    "type":"Forecast",
                    "Location":{
                        "i":"350896",
                        "lat":"50.8371",
                        "lon":"-0.7734",
                        "name":"LONDON",
                        "country":"ENGLAND",
                        "continent":"EUROPE",
                        "elevation":"14.0",
                        "Period":[
                        {
                            "type":"Day",
                            "value":"2017-05-28Z",
                            "Rep":[
                            {
                                "D":"SE",
                                "Gn":"9",
                                "Hn":"66",
                                "PPd":"51",
                                "S":"7",
                                "V":"GO",
                                "Dm":"22",
                                "FDm":"20",
                                "W":"7",
                                "U":"6",
                                "$":"Day"
                            },
                            {
                                "D":"ENE",
                                "Gm":"20",
                                "Hm":"85",
                                "PPn":"42",
                                "S":"9",
                                "V":"VG",
                                "Nm":"16",
                                "FNm":"15",
                                "W":"12",
                                "$":"Night"
                            }
                            ]
                        },
                        {
                            "type":"Day",
                            "value":"2017-05-29Z",
                            "Rep":[
                            {
                                "D":"SW",
                                "Gn":"13",
                                "Hn":"91",
                                "PPd": "59",
                                "S":"9",
                                "V":"GO",
                                "Dm":"18",
                                "FDm":"16",
                                "W":"12",
                                "U":"5",
                                "$":"Day"
                            },
                            {
                                "D":"W",
                                "Gm":"13",
                                "Hm":"93",
                                "PPn":"7",
                                "S":"7",
                                "V":"GO",
                                "Nm":"13",
                                "FNm":"12",
                                "W":"7",
                                "$":"Night"
                            }
                            ]
                        },
                        {
                            "type":"Day",
                            "value":"2017-05-30Z",
                            "Rep":[
                            {
                                "D":"WSW",
                                "Gn":"25",
                                "Hn":"75",
                                "PPd":"9",
                                "S":"13",
                                "V":"VG",
                                "Dm":"18",
                                "FDm":"15",
                                "W":"7",
                                "U":"5",
                                "$":"Day"
                            },
                            {
                                "D":"WNW",
                                "Gm":"13",
                                "Hm":"89",
                                "PPn":"5",
                                "S":"9",
                                "V":"VG",
                                "Nm":"11",
                                "FNm":"10",
                                "W":"0",
                                "$":"Night"
                            }
                            ]
                        },
                        {
                            "type":"Day",
                            "value":"2017-05-31Z",
                            "Rep":[
                            {
                                "D":"SW",
                                "Gn":"13",
                                "Hn":"58",
                                "PPd":"3",
                                "S":"4",
                                "V":"VG",
                                "Dm":"19",
                                "FDm":"18",
                                "W":"1",
                                "U":"7",
                                "$":"Day"
                            },
                            {
                                "D":"NE",
                                "Gm":"9",
                                "Hm":"87",
                                "PPn":"2",
                                "S":"4",
                                "V":"VG",
                                "Nm":"10",
                                "FNm":"9",
                                "W":"0",
                                "$":"Night"
                            }
                            ]
                        },
                        {
                            "type":"Day",
                            "value":"2017-06-01Z",
                            "Rep":[
                            {
                                "D":"ESE",
                                "Gn":"18",
                                "Hn":"56",
                                "PPd":"0",
                                "S":"9",
                                "V":"VG",
                                "Dm":"19",
                                "FDm":"18",
                                "W":"1",
                                "U":"8",
                                "$":"Day"
                            },
                            {
                                "D":"E",
                                "Gm":"13",
                                "Hm":"80",
                                "PPn":"1",
                                "S":"9",
                                "V":"VG",
                                "Nm":"11",
                                "FNm":"9",
                                "W":"0",
                                "$":"Night"
                            }
                            ]
                        }
                        ]
                    }
                }
        }
    }
```

The problem is I want to print out all the daytime high units, these are the Dm keys in the dictionaries, but I cannot gather all the data the keys correspond to in all the separate dictionaries into a list (or anything else). Any help on gathering them in any data type would be really helpful. My aim is to print out the dates with the daytime highs they correspond to.

Thank you for reading (and helping),
A noob to APIs

P.S. If it is needed, this is a copy of the script I'm using to get the information, it uses the Met Office (this is a weather forecast site in the UK) API:

```
import urllib.request, json, codecs

url = 'Insert API here'
json_obj = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
reader = codecs.getreader("utf-8")
data = json.load(reader(json_obj))
print (data)
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see, your data is nested in the `SiteRep -> DV -> Location -> Period` list, specifically its `Rep` elements, so all you need is to iterate through them, to pick up the `Dm` values and store in a list, stored as a dictionary with keys being each period's `value`. Something like:

```
dms = {}  # use this dict for storage
for period in data["SiteRep"]["DV"]["Location"]["Period"]:  # loop through periods
    # use Period's 'value' as a key; pick up Dm values and store them as value, as a list
    dms[period["value"]] = [v["Dm"] for v in period["Rep"] if "Dm" in v]

print(dms)
# {'2017-05-29Z': ['18'], '2017-05-28Z': ['22'], '2017-05-30Z': ['18'],
# '2017-05-31Z': ['19'], '2017-06-01Z': ['19']}
```

If `Dm` will never appear in the second list element of `Rep` (so single values only) you can further simplify it as:

```
dms = {}  # use this dict for storage
for period in data["SiteRep"]["DV"]["Location"]["Period"]:  # loop through periods
    # use Period's 'value' as a key; pick up Dm values and store them as value, as a list
    dms[period["value"]] = period["Rep"][0]["Dm"]

print(dms)
# {'2017-05-29Z': '18', '2017-05-28Z': '22', '2017-05-30Z': '18',
# '2017-05-31Z': '19', '2017-06-01Z': '19'}
```

Or even:

```
dms = {p["value"]: p["Rep"][0]["Dm"] for p in data["SiteRep"]["DV"]["Location"]["Period"]}

print(dms)
# {'2017-05-29Z': '18', '2017-05-28Z': '22', '2017-05-30Z': '18',
# '2017-05-31Z': '19', '2017-06-01Z': '19'}
```

which is the fastest but it becomes hard to read...

Answer (score 0):

Taking your data I can see that it contains:

- a dictionary with only one key, SiteRep which contains
- a dictionary with members `Wx` & `DV`

  - `Wx` is a dictionary with one key, `Param` and
  - `Param` is a list of dictionaries each of which contains members: `$`, `name` & `units` where `$` is the descriptive text. *Personally I would try to restructure this as a dictionary of dictionaries with name as the keys*

`data['SiteRep']['Wx']['Param'][0] ==> {
       '$': 'Feels Like Day Maximum Temperature', 
       'name': 'FDm', 
       'units': 'C'}`

But this can be mapped with:

```
params = {i['name']:(i['$'], i['units']) for i in data['SiteRep']['Wx']['Param']}
```

- DV is dictionary with keys of `dataDate`, `type` & `Location`

  - `DV['dataDate'] is simply '2017-05-28T17:00:00Z' i.e. when the data was generated.
  - 'DV['location']`is a dictionary with members`'i', 'lat', 'lon', 'name', 'country', 'continent', 'elevation', 'Period'` most of which are obvious.
  - `DV['location']['Period']` a list of length 5 *suggesting a 5 day forecast*
  - Each entry is a dictionary with keys `'type', 'value', 'Rep'` where type & value are 'Day' and a date respectively.
  - Each `DV['location']['Period'][`*n*`]['Rep']` is a list of 2 dictionaries each with members `'D', 'Gn', 'Hn', 'PPd', 'S', 'V', 'Dm', 'FDm', 'W', 'U', '$'` which just happens to be the names in `data['Wx']['Param']` with the exception of `$` which is either `Day` or `Night`

So basically all of the data you need is there you just need to drill down a bit.

Having used the mapping for `params` above and a local variable `D0` for `data['SiteRep']['DV']['Rep'][0]` I can print:

```
print('Date:', d0['value'])
for f in d0['Rep']:
    print(f['$'])
    for k,v in f.items():
        if k in params:
            print(params[k][0], v, params[k][1])
```

And get:

```
Date: 2017-05-28Z
Day                                               
Wind Direction SE compass                         
Wind Gust Noon 9 mph                              
Screen Relative Humidity Noon 66 %                
Precipitation Probability Day 51 %                
Wind Speed 7 mph                                  
Visibility GO                                     
Day Maximum Temperature 22 C                      
Feels Like Day Maximum Temperature 20 C           
Weather Type 7                                    
Max UV Index 6                                    
Night                                             
Wind Direction ENE compass                        
Wind Gust Midnight 20 mph                         
Screen Relative Humidity Midnight 85 %            
Precipitation Probability Night 42 %              
Wind Speed 9 mph                                  
Visibility VG                                     
Night Minimum Temperature 16 C                    
Feels Like Night Minimum Temperature 15 C         
Weather Type 12
```